# ¿Cómo pasar una imagen como atributo de un estado en ReactJSX? Para recibirlo como una propiedad en otro componente

Tags: reactjs, props

**Código de del componente Card**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="card-Games">
                <div>
                    <img src={this.props.imagen01} />
                    <h4>{this.props.name01}</h4>
                    {/*<a href="#">Agregar</a>*/}
                </div>

                <img src="" alt=""/>
                <div>
                    <img src={this.props.imagen02}  />
                    <h4>{this.props.name02}</h4>
                    {/*<a href="#">Agregar</a>*/}
                </div>


            {/*     Las imágenes son de prueba*/}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

*Como pueden ver en este código, meto cada imagen que quiero agregar al homepage cierto, pero lo que quiero es pasarle mis propias imágenes que tengo agregadas a mi Proyecto, estoy intentando importando la imagen que quiero mostrar en la etiqueta **div** Pero no se me esta mostrando, me serviría mucho si me pueden ayudar a ver el error, o buscar una solución posible de esta, muchas gracias de antemano*

**Código contenedor para todas las imágenes que se agreguen**

````
import Card from './cards/card';
import Callofduty from '../images/playstation/callofdutyMW.jpg'

export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); {
            this.state = {

                card1: {
                    img: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fifa/images/a/aa/FIFA_20_Regular_Edition.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20191002111706&path-prefix=es ' ,
                    name: 'FIFA 20',
                    subname: 'Lanzado 2019',
                },
                card2: {
                    img: {Callofduty},
                    name: 'FIFA 21',
                    subname: 'Lanzado 2020',
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home-content">
                {/* Probando las props para los contenidos individuales*/}
                <Card imagen01={this.state.card1.img}
                      name01={this.state.card1.name}
                />

                <Card imagen02={this.state.card2.img}
                      name02={this.state.card2.name}
                />

            </div>
        );
    }

} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solución.**

Tu razonamiento para pasar las props es correcto en cierta forma. Tu error se debe a los tipos que le estás pasando a tu componente y que te faltan props.

```
card2: {
                    img: {Callofduty},
                    name: 'FIFA 21',
                    subname: 'Lanzado 2020',
                }
```

`img` en `card2` es un objeto, pero en tu componente card, el `src` del `img` necesita una url.

```
card2: {
                        img: Callofduty,
                        name: 'FIFA 21',
                        subname: 'Lanzado 2020',
                    }
```

Bastaría con quitarle las llaves. Dado que la importación `Callofduty` ya hace referencia a un path.

Además, `Card` espera dos imágenes y en cada declaración sólo pasas una de las dos, pero nota que para hacer el render el componente depende de dos.
La forma actual de que tu componente reciba lo que necesita sería algo como:

```
<Card imagen01={...} name01={...} imagen02={...} name02={...}/>
```

Lo que se sería como decir que cada `Card` tiene dos imágenes. Lo cual no es incorrecto, sólo extraño. En dado caso el componente debería llamarse `<Cards/>` en plural. (Esto sólo es para no confundir al desarrollador o desarrolladora y mantener ciertas convenciones).

**Mi recomendación: Una mejor estructura acorde a la filosofía de React**.

Actualmente tu componente `Card` está fuertemente asociado con únicamente dos imágenes por `'Card'` y tiene un contentedor `'card-Games'`. Esto hace que tengas que declarar cada imagen que quieras tener en tu card, lo cual te llevaría mucho trabajo. Vamos a centrarnos en que un `Card` sólo puede tener el contenido de una imagen para usarlo así:

```
<Card content={algunCardContentCompatible}/>
```

Tu componente `Card` quedaría:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return(
                <div className="Card-styles">
                    <img src={this.props.content.img}/>
                    <h4>{this.props.content.name}</h4>
                </div>

        );
    }
}

Card.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.shape({
      img: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      subname: PropType.string
    })
  };
```

Para asegurarme de que estoy pasando los props correctos, estoy usando [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). ([Docs aquí](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)). Con esto sólo defino que mi componente `Card`, debe recibir como `props` un objecto `content` de la forma `{img: string, name: string, subname: string}`. De tal forma tener `this.props.content.img`, `this.props.content.name`y `this.props.content.subname`. Si algo sale mal, se desplegará un error en la consola del browser.

Finalmente, tu componente `Content`.

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './cards/card';
import Callofduty from '../images/playstation/callofdutyMW.jpg'

export default class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
                cards: [{
                    img: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fifa/images/a/aa/FIFA_20_Regular_Edition.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/310?cb=20191002111706&path-prefix=es',
                    name: 'FIFA 20',
                    subname: 'Lanzado 2019',
                }, {
                    img: Callofduty,
                    name: 'Call of Duty: Warzone',
                    subname: 'Lanzado 2020',
                }]
            }
    }
    

    const { cards } = this.state;


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home-content cards-container">
                {
                  cards.map((cardContent) => (<Card content={cardContent}/>))     
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Al final, sólo estoy agarrando los valores del array `cards` del `state`, de tal forma que obtengo algo como `[card1, card2, ..., cardN]`. Este array lo mapeo y cada valor del array lo paso como props a un componente `Card`. De esta forma, si agregas un nuevo objeto card (`{img, name, subname}`) al array `this.state.cards`, igual se añadirá sin tener que declarar estaticamente su valor en otro sitio. Con esto te evitas declarar de manera estatica cada imagen que debe de contener tu `Card` y sólo te centras en qué debería tener exclusivamente una.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Hola, de verdad muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicármelo de esta forma, me ha quedado mucho mas claro, y mucho mas fácil como mencionas para poder agregar las imágenes a cada etiqueta div, Gracias de antemano.